# Visual Studio 2015 stucks on running UWP

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a very strange problem with VS 2015 Professional. Suddenly every time that I try to start a UWP application, VS stucks and the app is not starting. I deleted the suo file and restarted VS, I tried also to repair VS but the problem remains. It seems that something doesn't let the apps to execute. Any ideas where the problem could be?

[image]

**Note**: I created and executed a Windows Forms Application with no problem at all.

Comment: Define "stuck". If you changed your debugging target from emulation to a device, or vice versa, you may be getting delays while the debugger waits either for the device or the emulator. If your target is the emulator, is it (and Hyper-V) active or have you disabled one of them?

Comment: It does nor respond. The app is not running either on local machine or a device although yesterday it was working. The truth is that I added a virtual switch via Hyper-V manager. Could this cause the problem?

Comment: So you are using the emulator? The emulator *is* a Hyper-V virtual machine. When you debug, the application is deployed to the emulated phone and the debugger attaches to it remotely. A network misconfiguration can cause problems, just as it would with any other VM

Comment: No I am not using the emulator always. Mainly I run it on Local Machine. But now just stucks after trying to run on Local Machine, on Emulator or on a Mobile Device. It is very strange ... VS can stuck while I am changing from ARM to x86, not building it just changing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the problem. I just disabled the Windows Phone Connection Internal Switch vEthernet Connection that I have created via the Hyper-V manager and now it works prefectly.